# Integrate Lombok with OpenCSV and JAXB

Tags: jaxb, lombok, opencsv

I am trying to write a code to convert csv to bean using opencsv and xml to bean using jaxb.

I tried using lombok.

The getters are not getting resolved even after lombok has generated them.

```
Exception with JAXB:
019-05-07 13:06:43.571 ERROR 16964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.r.readerimpl.XMLStatementReaderImpl    : JAXBException While reading the statement from XML


Exception with opencsv:
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.rabobank.readerrows.Record
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.***.readerrows.Record.<init>()
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Looking at your exception, it seems the problem is the missing no-arguments-constructor, but not a missing getter method.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. I had used @Data annotation. But it looks like it brings in required args constructor and not no args !